# svn update: local dir edit, incoming dir delete or move upon update

Tags: svn, merge, directory, conflict

I am doing an SVN Update in a folder with a repository.

Now I am getting

```
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
Tree conflict on 'SomeFolder'
   > local dir edit, incoming dir delete or move upon update
Select: (r) mark resolved, (p) postpone, (q) quit resolution, (h) help:
```

I have searched similar messages here at SO that seem not to apply (realting to file conflicts but not tree/dir conflicts). Especially, I do not see any real resolution option, something like "take theirs" or "take incoming".

How can I take incoming changes and overwrite local ones?

Comment: I chose (r) mark resolved, and then my local changes on a moved folder were marked for "add". Did "svn revert * -r" in that folder now, and that seems to have worked. (Tortoise just kept crashing.) "Check for modifications" is empty now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and can reproduce it with the following steps using Visual Studio:

1. Create a new branch from the trunk
2. Add a new project in Visual Studio
3. Add project to SVN and commit (ignore folder bin and obj on SVN level)
4. Make sure that there are no pending changes or unversioned files
5. Keep the project in Visual Studio open while performing switch to trunk
6. Get conflict on the newly added folder

Resolve conflict by reverting the change.
Visual studio will warn that the solution has changes, choose "reload all"

The main issue here is in step 5, I believe that Visual Studio is locking some files or directories. Repeating these steps when Visual Studio is closed gives no problems.

This is not only by crating a new project in the solution, switching to the new branch, open it in Visual Studio and switching back to the trunk gives the directory conflicts.

Comment: For me, Visual Studio was not involved, though it might create the same conflicts. (Since I don't have VS involved, not using it will also not help in my particular case.) Thanks anyway.